# Button submit not responding with modal in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I don't know why my "submit" button not responding. When I click on the edit button in each id, it can show a modal like this picture, so data is sent to the modal. But when I try to edit this data and click the button, it is not responding.

Here is my Index.cshtml

```
<div class="card-body">
                <table id="datatablesSimple">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:gray">
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ var stt = 1;}
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.List)
                        {
                            var itemName = "#exampleModalss" + item.id_category;
                            var itemName1 = "exampleModalss" + item.id_category;
                            <tr>
                                <td>@stt</td>
                                <td>@item.name</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                                            data-bs-target="@itemName">Edit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            stt++;

                            <form action="/Category/edit" method="post">
                                <div class="modal fade" id="@itemName1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Category Book</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="resultss" class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col">
                                                        <div class="">
                                                            <label for="category-film" class="col-form-label" style="font-weight:bold;width : 140px">Name Category: </label>
                                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" value=@item.name>
                                                            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="id_category" name="id_category" value=@item.id_category>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button style="width:100px" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult edit(FormCollection form)
        {
            Category cat = new Category();
            cat.id_category = Convert.ToInt32(form["id_category"]);
            category.edit(cat);
            return PartialView("Index", new { msg = "1" });
        }
```

My DAO

```
public void edit(Category category)
        {
            var result = myDb.categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.id_category == category.id_category);
            result.name = category.name;
            myDb.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Here is my result when clicking on the Edit button with each id of the category book.
[image]
I get stuck in it few days, anyone can help me. I think

Edited for details
[image: Here is my network]

[image: Here is my Console]

Comment: You have two Edit buttons - one inside the Form another outside the Form. Which one is not working for you?

Comment: @Rahatur submit button, my friend. Which in the modal footer. <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="submit" style="width:100px"  class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                            </div>

Comment: First, there is no "data is sent to the modal" as you put it. The modal is just a piece of HTML that is produced by your razor page. It is on the page before the button is clicked. It is just displayed on button click.
Secondly, to find why the form contained in a modal is not working, you need to debug. If you put a breakpoint in your edit post method, what happens? Does binding work (what do you get in your form parameter)? does validation work?
If you receive nothing, what does the network tab of your browser dev tools say? Is there a post request? to which URL? etc...

Comment: @ducnguyendinhtrung you need to let us know if there is any postback from the UI to the Action. Simply saying "Not working" is a very vague term.

Comment: @Rahatur i can't see any postback when iclick on Edit button (which i want to edit my name).

Comment: @ducnguyendinhtrung How did you check that? Using a break point in the action or from browser? Can you share a screenshot from the browser's developer tool? Which Browser are you using?

Comment: Please improve your question by describing precisely what you mean by "I can't see any postback". Just this sentence is too vague. Is there an HTTP post request made, or not? if yes to which URL?

Comment: @Rahatur i put break point in the action but when click on edit it still don't run into the break point. I think because the js which i import is conflict

Comment: Please open your browser dev tools, and look in the network tab if there is a post request when you click, and in the console tab, check if there is no javascript error. Let us know what you find.

Comment: On a side note: your form element should not enclose as much HTML. For instance the modal close button is a child of your form. If you use this button to close the modal it will also probably post your form. Also you should use the standard asp.net form tag helpers (asp-controller, asp-action). And you could have the right  types in your action parameters instead of relying on a less defined FormCollection type.

Comment: @LaurentGabiot thanks my friend, i just update more picture about network and console. All i want is when click on button, form is post and my category can change name. It is all i want

Comment: Sorry my friend with my little knowledge about fixing bug in network tab. Sorry

Comment: You need to learn this. When you click a submit button in a form, it should send an HTTP request, whose destination and type is defined by the attributes of the form element action and method. In your case, clicking on the button should create a POST request  to your website /category/edit.
Did you really click on the submit button? because on your screen shot there is no trace of a related POST request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238727/discussion-between-laurent-gabiot-and-duc-nguyendinh-trung).

Comment: My problem is solved, many thanks @LaurentGabiot

Answer (score 0):

FormCollection is for list your form is just about a name and category id
then your model is not appropriate please change your model i mean create model class which contain name and category.